# How to update the default HTML5 dropdown style?

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu

Is there a way to update the HTML5 default dropdown style ? For example default dropdown look like this

[image]

and my client required like

[image]

Could anyone please give a solution for this ? Is it even possible ? and my client expected to work this as native menu in Tablet devices. I ealier used WS:COMBO to get this style however, WS:COMBO is not acting as native menu in Tablet device therefore, I cannot use this. But is there a alternate CSS way to update the default HTML5 drop-down style ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Comment: well if yiou use the browser defaults. dont expect it to look like that on all tablets

Comment: so is there a way to balance the both

Answer (score 1):

I think most closer and better solution is using http://www.jqfancyfields.com/ plugin and updating it's sprite image to match the design.